# Why I get error in validation form in angular?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have created an Angular form and I want to validate the inputs. This line should validate the address:

```
<span *ngIf='submitted && f.caddress.errors' class="invalid-feedback">Customer address is required!</span>
```

but I come up with this error:

**Property 'caddress' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['caddress'].**

This is .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {


  
  customerForm!:FormGroup;
  submitted =false;

  constructor(
    private formbuilder:FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router:Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onSubmit();}

  onSubmit() { 
    this.customerForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      uname : ['', Validators.required],
      cphone : ['', Validators.required],
      caddress : ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
  get f(){
    return this.customerForm.controls
  }

  submitCustomer(){
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.customerForm.invalid){
      return;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: try this `f['caddress'].errors.required`

Answer (score 0):

The error says what you want to do. you need to use `f[caddress].errors.required` instead of `f.caddress.errors`

inside the `FromGroup` controls look like below,

```
controls: {
    [key: string]: AbstractControl;
};
```

So, when you refer `formControlName` you need to use `this.customerForm.controls[caddress]` or `this.customerForm.get('caddress')`

you can check error like this `this.customerForm.get('caddress').error.required`